# ssh not working, muxserver_listen bind(): No such file or directory

Tags: git, macos, ssh, terminal

Today on my **new work laptop** I'm not able to use ssh at all (ssh into server, bitbucket, etc not working), it failed with the following error:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make
>   sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

So I started debugging and this is the output for ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([131.103.20.168]:22).
debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
muxserver_listen bind(): No such file or directory
```

No idea what is wrong, I used ssh several times and never had this issue. I'm using osx by the way.

This question was closed as of topic, but in my opinion SSH is a tool used in everyday developing, please consider re opening it

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After trying a lot of different things I found that I was missing this folder **~/tmp**, I realized of this after checking here: **/private/etc/ssh_config**. I found this line:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/tmp/ssh-mux-%h-%p-%r #THIS WAS THE PROBLEM
```

So after:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
```

everything works again.

I thought of answering my own question since it took me some time to find this.

Comment: yes. It is all right to answer your question. But don't forget to mark it as a solution.

Comment: Will do it after 2 days

Comment: I personally prefer `ControlPath ~/.ssh/.control-%C` when `%C` (hash) is available and `ControlPath ~/.ssh/.control-%h:%p:%r` otherwise.  This is a safe and out-of-the-way place (`~/.ssh` must have strict permissions, must exist for SSH to work, and SSH creates it for you anyway). Having them as dotfiles makes them inobtrusive when you run e.g. `ls ~/.ssh`.

Comment: I was getting a similar message using ssh with connection sharing. Just to clear up any confusion, this directory (`~/.ssh/sockets/` in my case) needs to exist on the machine you are sshing *from*.
I created it on the destination machine, which did not resolve the problem.